# Add a third column to existing CSV

Tags: python, csv

I have a CSV file with 2 Columns (x,y) and 5653 rows formated like this

```
0,0
1,0
2,0
3,0
4,0
5,0
....
102,0
102,1
101,1
....
0,1
0,2
1,2
....
```

Now I want to add a third column to it out of another csv with meassured values eg -89 etc those are mean values.
these are also 5653 rows and its the first column of that file?
Now how can I read the first file read the second file and put it like this

```
0,0,-89
1,0,-89
2,0,-89
3,0,-89
4,0,-90
5,0,-90
6,0,-89
7,0,-89
8,0,-89
9,0,-89
```

So I want the values to be the same just in one CSV

Comment: Which part exactly are you stuck on?

Comment: i can write files but i dont know hot to append a column to one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the library pandas which is build to work with tabular data.
typical workflow:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_csv("your_path") # df is a shorthand for dataframe, a name for tabular data.

df2 = pd.read_csv("csv2")

# concanating: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html
result = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1) # join by row, not by column
result.to_csv("path")
```

Comment: This leads `result.to_csv("out.csv")` to be empty

Comment: Okay, it works but now i get a csv file with the following output `10,11,0,-89.0` cant i get rid of the index?

Comment: there is an option on to_csv

Comment: yeah its `result.to_csv("out.csv",index=False)` Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module which unlike [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/) does not require you to install any third-party libraries. You can just [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) the two readers:

```
import csv

with open('in1.csv') as fin1:
    with open('in2.csv') as fin2:
        with open('out.csv') as fout:
            r1 = csv.reader(fin1)  # iterator over lists of strings
            r2 = csv.reader(fin2)
            w = csv.reader(fout)
            for row1, row2 in zip(r1, r2):
                w.writerow(row1 + row2[:1])  # row from 1 + first column from 2
```

Comment: Thanks, this works aswell, but i prefer working with pandas